# Incorrect result in sequence of futures/either

Tags: scala

Given the code below that combines sequence of futures and Either, I always get printed "not OK", why is that if the result is a List?

```
def future1 (i: Int) = Future { if (i==0) Right(1) else Left("error 1") }
def future2 (i: Int) = Future { if (i==0) Right(2) else Left("error 2") }

...
...

val f1 = future1(0)
val f2 = future2(0)
val f3 = Future.sequence(Seq(f1, f2))

f3.map { result =>
    result match {
      case List(r) => println("ok")
      case _ => println("not OK)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`case List(r)` would only match a list with one element which would be then bound to `r`. 
To check if the result is an instance of type `List` use

```
f3.map { result =>
  result match {
    case r: List[_] => println("ok")
    case _ => println("not OK)
  }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, assuming that `Seq` is `List` seems a bit questionable.